# Using a UIVisualEffect, the blurred view sometimes doesn't update

Tags: ios, ios8, uiblureffect

I have the following code in the layoutSubviews method of one of my views:

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.blurView.frame.size.width, self.blurView.frame.size.height);

[self.blurView addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

`self.blurView` corresponds to an IBOutlet in a nib of a given region of my view which I want blurred in that cool iOS 8 way. That particular region features an often changing graphic.

My problem is that sometimes when my graphic changes and I bring up my blur view, the blurred image is a graphic which is no longer there. It's as though the blur view hasn't noticed that the superview has changed.

Are there any strategies to assure that the blurred view is the currently presenting graphic?

Comment: I faced this problem as well. I way I fixed it was using `DispatchQueue` to initialize the visual effect view view after some delay in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 3):

Another to force the UIVisualEffectsView is to change the background color temporarily to a different color, then back to the original.  This forces recalculation as well, and doesn't create an error (like you get if you try to change the alpha value).

I have two UIVisualEffectsViews (one extra light and one dark), and after making changes to the background image of the overall view, I call this little method that updates the effects views.

```
-(void)refreshBlurViews {
    self.lightVisualEffect.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.lightVisualEffect.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.darkVisualEffect.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.darkVisualEffect.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Hope that helps someone along the way!

Answer (score 2):

I run into this all the time I use UIVisualEffect and what worked out better (it's not a perfect solution still in my opinion) is to include it inside of a "viewWillAppear" type of method. This way, the visual effect is rendered when the views under it are ready, rather than adding the visual effect view before the views under it are not rendered

Answer (score 0):

There are two strategies to overcome this problem with the API:

1. Use a new UIVisualEffectView each time
2. Animate the UIVisualEffectView's alpha property

The first strategy is more code than the second, but each is equally as effective at reseting the UIVisualEffectView's blurred view. The reason that (1) and (2) work is that (1) forces it to resample below it, I presume and (2) does as well. But why does (2) do this?

The reason (2) resamples below it is because Apple's API won't blur the background of a UIVisualEffectView if you're animating it's alpha property. The tell us this in the following comment:

```
 /*
 Proper use of this class requires some assistance on your part. Namely:

 • Avoid alpha values < 1 ...

 */
```